# How to set a layout specific for a tablet 9.7"

Tags: android, android-layout

I know I can set a folder called layout-small, normal, etc.. for different screen sizes, but I want to set an specific folder for a tablet 9.7". Is it possible??

Comment: What's the model name of the tablet?

Comment: Woxter Tablet PC 97 IPS 9.7" 16GB Dual WX529 TabletPC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the [DOC](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#SmallestScreenWidthQualifier) you can use `layout-sw<dp>`.

sw means "smallest width", and indicates the "shortest dimension of the available screen area". Usually 600 is for screens such as 600x1024 mdpi (7" tablet) and 720 for screens such as 720x1280 mdpi (10" tablet).

Based on the screen size of your tablet create your layout and put it in a folder named `layout-sw720`. Then test it directly with the emulator or your device.

Comment: I've created a folder named 'layout-sw768dp' and it's working. Thanxs a lot.

Answer (score 0):

layout-sw720 is for the 3.0+ 10 inch tab you can use it otherwise make a entirely different layout and pick it yourself at runtime based on screen width and height